# Cannot authenticate user in Meteor 1.3 with userAccounts

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I have a custom form in a template with 2 fields, email and password.
When the form is submitted, I'm doing the following:

```
Template.signin.events({
  'submit form': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let email = $('[name=email]').val();
    let password = $('[name=password]').val();

    Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('submit err: ', err);
        return err;
      }
    });

  }
});
```

And I see this error in the browser console:

> errorClass {error: 403, reason: "error.accounts.Login forbidden", details: undefined, message: "error.accounts.Login forbidden [403]", errorType: "Meteor.Error"}

I can register a user with a very similar logic, by calling `Meteor.call('ATCreateUserServer')`.

Comment: Are you validating login attempts with [`accountsServer.validateLoginAttempt(func)`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_validateloginattempt)?

Comment: I'm not. It should be it. I saw it before in the documentation but Its not very clear how to use it.